# How to create a Chord diagram out of this dataset format?

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, holoviews, chord-diagram

I have a dataset which consists of passes made and received by a player with every teammate. A sample dataset looks like this:

```
            ter Stegen  Pique  Rakitic  Busquets  Coutinho  Suarez  Messi  \
ter Stegen           0      8        0         2         0       1      1   
Pique               12      0        2        20         0       0      1   
Rakitic              3      3        0        13         5       2      6   
Busquets             1      1        9         0         0       0      8   
Coutinho             0      0        2         1         0       4      6   
Suarez               0      0        2         1         2       0      1   
Messi                0      2        5         1         3       4      0   
Lenglet              4      6        8         8         1       0      0   
Alba                 1      1        8         4         5       8      5   
Roberto              4     11        5         4         0       4      6   
Vidal                1     10        5         8         3       2      7   

            Lenglet  Alba  Roberto  Vidal  
ter Stegen        4     3        5      5  
Pique             9     2       10      5  
Rakitic           4     8        2      5  
Busquets          4     8        7     12  
Coutinho          0     3        0      1  
Suarez            0     5        3      3  
Messi             0     4        3      4  
Lenglet           0     4        0      4  
Alba              6     0        1      4  
Roberto           1     0        0      8  
Vidal             5     7        6      0
```

How do I visualize this in the form of a chord diagram which shows the flow of passes from every player to every other? I've tried using  `Holoviews` and `Plotly` but I can't crack how to work with data in this format. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's the entire code:

```
import pandas as pd
import holoviews as hv
from holoviews import opts, dim
from bokeh.plotting import show, output_file
import numpy as np

pd.set_option("display.max_columns",11)
hv.extension('bokeh')
hv.output(size = 200)

df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\Abhishek\BarLiv.csv")
df = df.set_index("0")
df.index.name = None
#print(df)


# Declare a gridded HoloViews dataset and call dframe to flatten it
players = list(df.columns)
data = hv.Dataset((players, players, df), ['source', 'target']).dframe()
#print(players)

# Now create your Chord diagram from the flattened data
chord = hv.Chord(data)
chord.opts(
    node_color='index', edge_color='source', label_index='index', 
    cmap='Category10', edge_cmap='Category10', width=500, height=500)

output_file('chordtest.html')
show(hv.render(chord))
```

Edit 1: Here's what I'm getting after implementing @philippjfr's solution 
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HoloViews has provides a neat little trick that makes this pretty easy, you can declare a gridded Dataset from your dataframe and then flatten it:

```
df = pd.read_csv('/Users/philippjfr/Downloads/BarLiv.csv', index_col=0)

# Declare a gridded HoloViews dataset and call dframe to flatten it
data = hv.Dataset((list(df.columns), list(df.index), df),
                  ['source', 'target'], 'value').dframe()

# Now create your Chord diagram from the flattened data
chord = hv.Chord(data)
chord.opts(
    node_color='index', edge_color='source', label_index='index', 
    cmap='Category10', edge_cmap='Category10', width=500, height=500)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, this throws up this Error: `ERROR:bokeh.core.validation.check:E-1001 (BAD_COLUMN_NAME): Glyph refers to nonexistent column name. This could either be due to a misspelling or typo, or due to an expected column being missing. : LegendItem(id='1479', ...)`

Comment: Furthermore, the resultant plot always looks too symmetrical - it's probably not reading the data, I've edited my question to include the plot.

Comment: I think you probably don't have the latest versions of the underlying libraries. The output doesn't look right either, I'd suggest you 1) update to the latest versions of bokeh and holoviews 2) confirm that my test code produces the right plot 3) post the CSV somewhere.

Comment: I just upgraded all libraries - bokeh, Holoviews and the same error still persists. I'm running Holoviews version `1.12.2`. My Python version is `3.7` and I'm on Windows(64-bit). The actual csv file is pretty small; I've updated the sample csv in the question to include it

Comment: From the little I understand, I assume something went wrong while flattening the data. I print `data` and only get the names of the players in both columns and none of the data

Comment: I've updated the answer with the real data and some small fixes for declaring the dataset. In future please post a link to the CSV, converting an HTML formatted table is a lot of effort.

Comment: That worked for me, thanks a lot. I'll keep that in mind from next time. I couldn't figure out a way to link to a csv file and hence my attempt at updating the question with the data